# Yesod Persistent atomic interaction

Tags: database, performance, haskell, yesod, acid

I was completely missing the point of database opened connection and rollback feature so I was using `runDB myAction` every time, because I didn't realize what was going on. Today I made some tests to try to understand how it does the rollback, and one of them was this:

```
getTestR :: Handler Text
getTestR = do
 runDB $ insert $ Test 0
 runDB $ do
   forM_ [1..] $ \n -> do 
     if n < 10
       then do
         insert $ Test n
         return ()
       else undefined
 return "completed"
```

I got an `undefined` error at runtime, as expected, and only the first `runDB` action got in the database, the second `runDB` got rolled back and when I inserted another registry, its id started with 9 positions ahead the last persisted element.

Suppose I have to do 2 `get`s  actions in the database, and I do them in two ways, first I do:

```
getTestR :: FooId -> BooId-> Handler Text
getTestR fooid booid = do
  mfoo <- runDB $ get fooid
  mboo <- runDB $ get booid
  return "completed"
```

and then I try:

```
getTest'R :: FooId -> BooId-> Handler Text
getTest'R fooid booid = do
  (mfoo, mboo) <- runDB $ do
     mfoo <- get fooid
     mboo <- get booid
     return (mfoo,mboo)
  return "completed"
```

Which would be the actual overall difference? I think that in this case database consistence is not an issue, but performance may be (or will Haskell laziness make them equal because `mfoo` and `mboo` are never used so they are never queried?). Probably these questions look very nonsense, but I would like to be sure I don't have gaps in my understandings.

Comment: Haskell is very great, I think the mind of a programmer exposed to Haskell during a fairly good time will never regress to its original state. It's like programming with increased power, constantly making improvements in our own minds and consequentially in our general coding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have answered your own question while discussing two DB actions. 'runDB' has following signature.

```
runDB :: YesodDB site a -> HandlerT site IO a
```

`YesodDB` is a ReaderT transformer monad. runDb lifts DB action to IO action. In the first example, there are two separate IO actions (not DB action). In the second snippet, there is only a single DB action. In the first example, one or both actions may succeed. But in the second one, you will either get result of two `get`s or an error.

As there are two `IO` actions wrapping up two `runDB`s, the DB interaction is not optimized, as each runDB represents a single action. In second however, the two actions will share same connection.

You might want to have a look at [YesodPersistentBackend](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-persistent-1.4.0.4/docs/Yesod-Persist-Core.html#t:YesodPersistBackend) and use getDBRunner for for sharing connection from a pool.

Comment: Can you explain better this part: "In the first example, there are two separate IO actions (not DB action)."

Comment: runDB relies on associated backend tyoe, which defaults to persistent library's SqlBackend type, runDb would essentially calls runSqlPool to execute action. runSQLpool gets connection from the pool, runs the action, and returns the connection. (No reuse of the connection). Hence two runDB means two connections being used for each.